# Does the Wii U use HDCP copy protection on on games via its HDMI output?

Tags: recording, wii-u

I'd like to record gaming videos via HDMI on the Wii U, so I wonder if its HDMI output is protected by HDCP, which would mean I'd need to use another output method to record. I've googled a bit and found extremely conflicting reports of whether the Wii U has [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) or not, and none of the people stating yes/no seem to have actually tried to record with it.

Is there any confirmation either way? Better yet, a video showing it is possible (if it is)?

Comment: FWIW I'll probably get a chance to test this out tonight if my Wii U is delivered, but there really ought to be a canonical answer to this, not 10 forum threads saying "yes wait no wait maybe yes I dunno lol"

Comment: The confusion likely comes from the other end of the system (not the Wii U) supporting the protocol or not.

Comment: If the Wii U ever wants to display media from any of the standard sources it would have to support HDCP.  Technically HDCP is part of the standard for HDMI, so if Wii U supports HDMI, it literally has to support HDCP.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't care if it supports it, I care if it *uses* it. Not all HDMI traffic is HDCP encrypted; the 360 can be recorded over HDMI, but the PS3 cannot, due to this protection

Comment: @BenBrocka - The 360 uses HDCP through the Video store.  During gameplay thats another story.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, I only care about games' output, I'll put that in the title

Comment: @Ramhound  "Support" is meaningless here: HDCP is only part of the HDMI spec so that HDMI output devices *may* participate in pathways that require HDCP, but HDMI output devices are not *required* to encode using HDCP. HDCP is only used by the output device if 1) the receiver requires it, 2) the disc the device is playing requires it (i.e., Blu-Ray, DVD, HD-DVD), or 3) the device manufacturer enables it for media not required by the HDCP license (i.e., video game video output). So the Wii U will only require HDCP for video games if Nintendo decided that they wanted to, but no spec requires it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wii U is completely HDCP-free when playing games, accessing the menu and even when playing Wii/ Wii Virtual Console software. I confirmed this using my Elgato Game Capture HD, which doesn't have an HDCP stripper.

This means any HDMI capture card can capture Wii U video even if it can't strip/crack HDCP protection (no promises about Netflix/non game content, those are often intended to use HDCP). Note that you can't record the Wii U gamepad's video using just a capture card on the Wii U's HDMI cable though, but you can record the TV screen's portion just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The 2015 update (for those running into this)

The WiiU deliberately blocks certain games from being captured.

Wind Waker is a no go, meanwhile Mario Party 10 recorded just fine.

So the WiiU selectively uses HDCP to block revording certain & particular video games. It all depends on Nintendo.